# Why I'm seeing a lock besides the partition I'm trying to modify with gparted?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I wanted to create more space for Ubuntu on my hard disk in favor of my Windows partition. I booted the livecd and resized the NTFS partition to 100 GB. Then I wanted to resize my Ubuntu (ext4) partition to fill up the created unallocated space.

A screenshot of my current disk. (With the livecd there's no 'key' icon after sda6)

[image: a screenshot of my current disk]

My first thought was just right click on sda6 → move/resize → done. Unfortunately I cannot resize or move the partition. However I can resize the NTFS partition.

I guess it is because the extended sda4 partition is locked. I couldn't see an unlock possibility though…

So how do I resize the ext4 partition anyway, probably by unlocking the extended partition, but how?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You cannot resize a mounted filesystem, that's why you see a lock icon.

You were doing well, you booted into a Live CD and resized the NTFS partition.

Now you need to enlarge the Extended partition, partitions "inside" that extended partition cannot "escape" outside.

1. Make sure that `/dev/sda6` is unmounted. If a lock icon is visible, right click on it and choose for *Unmount*
2. Make sure that the swap partition `/dev/sda5` is unmounted. Right click on it and choose for *Swapoff*
3. Select `/dev/sda4` and choose for Resize. Use the free space on the left side
4. Select `/dev/sda6` and resize it on the right side
5. Apply the changes and you're done.

Comment: @arian Yeah, the screenshot you provided suggests that its still mounted (hence why you can't do anything with the drive).  And also, you're right, @Lekensteyn, that extended partition needs to be resized first to make that space available for the partitions inside that (we didnt have this information before now :P)

Comment: right, sda4 is still locked (in the live-cd too), and sda6 is unlocked so I cannot resize my extended partition to make size available. That's probably the problem here.

Comment: @arian: it seems that the swap partition is always mounted. Check the new instructions.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! It took a while (1.5 hours) but everything seems to work fine. I had to use a margin of about 5mbs on the left because initially I got an error message.

Answer (score 11):

For a start boot with your live CD.

Press <kbd>Start</kbd> and type `Gparted`:

[image: open gparted]

Once you open the program you will see a list with your partitions. Now to make any changes, we have to unmount the partitions we want to edit. Right-Click on the partition, and choose *Unmount*:

[image: unmount partition]

Let's assume that I want to decrease the size of **sda1** and add it in **sda3**. Right-Click on **sda1** and choose *Resize/Move*

[image]

A new windows will pop out were we can make our changes. Now to decrease the size, drag the Right arrow to the left. You can also type a custom value next to the option *New size (MB):*. Once you choose the new size click on the button *Resize/Move*

[image]

Now a new box will appear with the label unallocated. We will now add this free space at **sda3** partition.

[image]

Right-Click on **sda3** and choose *Resize/Move*

[image]

Drag the left arrow to the left as shown below:

[image]

Hit the button *Resize/Move* to submit the change.

Finally, click on the "tick" button to apply all your changes.

[image]

Comment: How about Ubuntu server without GUI?!

Answer (score 3):

**A partition cannot be resized when Ubuntu is running off of it, or it is mounted.**

You can use a live CD:

1. Boot the setup CD(live CD) and select to "**Try Ubuntu**".
2. Once it boots, start **GParted** and right-click the partition. Unmount it.
3. Then, *delete* or *resize* any partitions to the *left* or the *right* of the partition in question.
4. Now, right-click the partition and resize it.
5. Click **Apply** on the GParted window and let it finish.

   You need to "Apply" since the changes are not done until this step. They are only queued up when you perform operations in GParted.

#### Don't forget to make a backup of any important data!

Answer (score 1):

You should boot into a LiveCD to use gparted to resize your active ext4 partition - its unwise to modify partitions while they're actively being used (especially the active system partition which is ext4)

Afterwards, you should be able to move and resize the partition within that LiveCD environment, and the changes will be done when you boot back to the ext4 partition and not the LiveCD

Comment: Yeah, I did boot into the livecd (see my second sentence :))

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can with **GParted**.

1. Boot from Ubuntu live CD.
2. Launch GParted.
3. Select the Ubuntu partition in question and click on **Resize/Move** from the GParted toolbar or select **Partition** menu → **Resize/Move** - provided that the gained unallocated space is right next to the Ubuntu partition in question.

   If the unallocated space is *not* adjacent to the Ubuntu partition, then you either have to move or shrink partitions to be able to put the unallocated space adjacent to the Ubuntu partition to be able to resize it.

   For a more detailed information, take a look at these sites:

   http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html

   http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2036-how-to-resize-a-partition-using-gparted-on-linux

   http://gparted.sourceforge.net/larry/resize/resizing.htm

   http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/

Answer (score 0):

use lvdisplay to see the mounted volume
use lvremove "volume name" or
use vgremove "volume group name"

the are the first 2 names displayed after running the lvdisplay command.

My system had pve partition and swap  the automounted from Gparted live. Would not deactivate or unmount via command. Lvdisplay then vgremove worked fine. I was then able. to delete the partion the the. Gparted GUI.

Comment: Hello. There is nothing in the question asked that says or implies the use of an lvm. Therefore your answer makes no sense.