# How do I change the size of an ext4 partition?

Tags: partitioning, ext4, resize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resize partition with GParted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/resize-partition-with-gparted)

I upgraded the hdd in my FOG server (Ubuntu 11.4) to 500gb but I can't find a simple way to enlarge the partition to take up the empty space.
I image its simple enough but I have very little experience with ubuntu/linux so things will require some dumbing down...
Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Take your server off-line for a little while and use Gparted Live CD to do the deed. It can increase the partition without loosing any data.