# Utility for resizing partitions

Tags: partitioning, ext4, disk-utility

Is there a partition utility in Ubuntu from which I can break my existing 'ext4' partition into more partition w/o loosing this partition's data?[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/51272/4982

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can with gparted it is part of ubuntu.
Be sure to resize that partition first (shrink it) and freespace that left will be turned in unallocated space. Make new partition from that unallocated space.
You can shrink it with graphic slider.

Comment: the partition that i need to resize has the filesystem, on gparted this partition is not showing the option of 'resize' whereas other small partition does. Moreover it is showing an option of 'unmount' is it safe to unmount the drive when it has the ubuntu file system?

Comment: Gparted should show option "resize/move" and shouldn't show option "unmount". If you have installed Windows run chkdsk for file system errors. Don't click on unmount im meantime. Are yoou running ubuntu from live media or you instaled it previously on hard drive?

Comment: windows is not install, i have yet to install windows, the partition is flaged 'boot' and is not showing 'resize/move'. The only available options are 'Unmount' and 'Manage flags'

Comment: ubuntu is installed on a hard drive

Comment: can you upload printscreen of your gparted screen. im intrested how bar that shows partitions look alike

Comment: attached screenshot

Answer (score 0):

you can use  gparted which can be installed by typing into a terminal

"sudo apt-get install gparted" (without quotes)

and then by either pressing alt-f2 or in a terminal write "gksudo gparted" (without quotes)

gparted help is located here http://gparted.sourceforge.net/help.php

---

edit: read your modification to the question.

you have to **unmount** the partition to edit it. also you may use a live cd/usb to edit the partition, too. with same steps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can,t make another partition because you already have 4 primary partitions. AFAIK is the maximum primary partitions supported, you could make new partitions inside the Extended partition but it is small so...

You would have to delete the **swap** partition and then shrink the **root** partition to get space and then make the swap partition again and will need to **set the new swap partition** in *Fstab* to be mounted at startup.