# I have only one partition but I want to have one more

Tags: boot, partitioning

I have only one partition in ubuntu where my boot files are also there. I want to have one more partition how can i do it?

Comment: Try GParted but you need to boot to a liveCD and run GParted from there since you cannot modify partitions while they are in use. Then in the GParted window, select your partition and resize it which will result to unallocated space. You can then format the gained space to any file-system you want.

Comment: @SumanGaudel Do you mean that you do not have a separate `/boot` partition, and you want to modify your existing Ubuntu installation so that you do? Or do you mean something else? Please edit your question to provide as many more details as possible about what you are trying to accomplish. Please also open a Terminal window (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`), run `mount` and `df -h` (separately), and edit your question to include the output of each.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the partition of the bootfiles. You can resize it with livecd. This is the complete guide of partitioning:
[Why I'm seeing a lock besides the partition I'm trying to modify with gparted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/resize-partition-with-gparted)

After resize, you can add a new partition.

Comment: This assumes a separate `/boot` partition already exists. If the goal is to create one (where only a `/` exists), that will require moving files, editing `/etc/fstab`, and reinstalling GRUB, none of which are covered in [that guide](http://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/resize-partition-with-gparted).