# Failed to partition my drive for installing dual boot Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 as my operating system. I tried to install Windows 7 along with Ubuntu.

To do so I inserted the Windows CD and booted. When it asked for partitioning the drive, I clicked drive options "advanced" to partition. But then I couldn't click on 'new' and failed to create a partition.

How can my problem be solved?

Comment: How many partitions on the disk?

Answer (score 1):

Windows will refuse to see and change any Linux partitions on your drive. It is therefore recommended to change the partitions from a live Ubuntu session as was further elaborated in this answer:

- [Why I'm seeing a lock besides the partition I'm trying to modify with gparted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/resize-partition-with-gparted)

> [**Please do take the time to backup your data before you change partitions or install another OS.**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)

For installing another OS (e.g. Windows) it is best practise to leave an unpartitioned space on the drive and let the installer partition and format it. Note that you cant have more than 4 primary partitions.

After having installed Windows you will have to repair Grub to be able to boot Ubuntu again:

- [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Simple and perfect answer!

Answer (score 0):

Windows overwrites the original boot loader (GRUB). You need that boot-loader to select which OS to go to. To install the boot loader again, enter to the installation process from your thumbdrive ( you can boot ubuntu from your thumbdrive easily, Google it to find out more).

1) Installation (CUSTOM)

2) create a "SWAP AREA" partition of 500 MB, from the beginning (logical).
Click continue, it should install a fresh copy of the data. REMEMBER TO BACKUP ALL YOUR IMPORTANT STUFFS. THERE ARE MANY OTHER ALTERNATIVES.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is a turd, you have to install WINDOWS first, then create a new partition in windows (as FAT32), then boot up Ubuntu LiveCD/USB and install it.