# Cannot resize Ubuntu partition

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resize partition with GParted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/resize-partition-with-gparted)

I've been using Ubuntu for about a month now, and I'm still having difficulties adopting to it.

One issue that I've been facing for few weeks now is that the Ubuntu partition is running out of space (I setup only 6GB of space for it and now I have less than 300MB available).

I tried to follow the instructions which I've found in some threads here, but non worked.

[image]

I'm trying to add the 3.79GB (sda7) to Ubuntu partition (ext4).

When I click the right button over ext4, the only options I have are [**Unmount**, **Manage flags**, **Information**)... and while sda7 only [**Delete**, **Format to**, **Manage flags**, **Information**) are available.

Can anyone tell me, what am I doing wrong?