# How do I partition my hardrive?

Tags: partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resize partition with GParted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/resize-partition-with-gparted)

I am a complete and total newbie when it comes to ubuntu and don't happen to be tech savvy to begin with. I've tried to wrap my head around the user invasive interface with what resources I can find but obviously don't seem to be looking in the right places. To get to the point i'm running into a lack of partitioned space. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on one hardrive and XP on the other (which I can't get to boot either but I think thats because of a video hardware/software/whatnot problem). What other information do i need to provide in order to begin here?

Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: How do you know you're "running into a lack of partitioned space"? Please provide those details. Also, if you search this site, you'll find a lot of information on partitioning.

Comment: Well I've seen errors saying so whenever I attempt to download various files. For example when I was trying to download gparted something to the effect of "not enough disk space" followed the attempted installation in the cp. I've tried looking through some posted Q&A's all over and have managed to get the partition editor installed and running, its where to get started that i'm having an issue with. I don't know how to partition a drive that im running on (or any other for that matter).

Comment: so are you able to install **gparted** now? or you still receive the error message "not enough disk space"?

Comment: Yes i was able to install gparted after clearing out some uneeded files, trash bin, and uninstalling unused programs.

Comment: **You *can't* resize your Ubuntu partition in GParted on installed system itself.** That's why GParted isn't installed by default. Run it from a live CD/DVD/USB instead. See [Resize partition with GParted](http://askubuntu.com/q/51272), [Cannot resize Ubuntu partition](http://askubuntu.com/q/213413), [How to increase my Ubuntu disk space?](http://askubuntu.com/a/213542/22949), [How do I free up disk space?](http://askubuntu.com/q/5980), [How to increase disk space?](http://askubuntu.com/q/33907), [What is taking up so much space on my disk, beside the filesystem?](http://askubuntu.com/q/17467)

Comment: Awesome thank you! now that i've unmounted the drive i wanted to work on how do I remount it afterwards?

Comment: @Devon If you boot form a live CD/DVD/USB, the only partition that might be in use is the swap partition. Are you asking how to re-enable swap in the live environment? Once you boot back into the installed system, everything is mounted again. (That is to say, whether or not a filesystem is mounted is not preserved across reboots.)

Comment: Now, if you change where your Ubuntu system's `/` or `/boot` partition *starts*, or where an extended partition that contains them *starts*, or if you renumber your partitions or insert additional partitions before those for `/` or `/boot`, you may have to [reinstall GRUB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal), which involves manually remounting the `/` partition (and the `/boot` partition if you have one). But generally speaking, you don't manually remount your partitions--you make the changes, then boot back into the installed system and they're mounted.