# How to increase my Ubuntu disk space?

Tags: 12.04, installation, wireless, windows, workspaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resize partition with GParted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/resize-partition-with-gparted)

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7. During Ubuntu installation, I shrinked the Windows drive 10GB and Ubuntu installed in this space. Now I want to increase this space. I again shrink the drive to make another 10GB unallocated space.

Can I add this space to the Ubuntu disk space?