# Resizing my ubuntu ext4 partition

Tags: gparted

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resize partition with GParted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/resize-partition-with-gparted)

I want to resize my ubuntu sda5 partition (basically merge it with the unallocated 87 GB space). but the Resize/move option for sda5 is not working / enabled in gparted.
Appreciate response in lay man terms.

Comment: I'm guessing the partition you want to resize is still mounted ("in use") so it can't be resized. If you can't unmount it (e.g. because its your system partition) use a USB live stick. Boot from the stick and run gparted in the live system.