# Ubuntu Installation Partitioning Gone Wrong

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning, uninstall

I wanted to install Ubuntu 12.4 LTS beside my Windows 7. So I put the CD and booted my PC, everything was easy, but I wanted to give Ubuntu **200GB** and instead I gave it more than a terabyte. Now, my Windows 7 has just 288GB free space. Also Linux-swap has 12GiB which i think is too much. It should be 3GB. Is that correct?

Here is an image of GParted and the Partitions:

[image]

Now, I wanted to ask what is the best way to fix all this. How can I be sure what sda1,sda2,sda3,sda4,sda5,sda6 is ? I don't want to destroy my Windows 7.

Should I just delete Ubuntu 12.4 LTS and give the partitions back to Windows? How can I do that? How should I uninstall Ubuntu and how can I give the partition back to Windows 7?

Or, should I use the GParted and shrink the partitions of Ubuntu and give the rest to Windows 7? How should I do that step by step? Is it better then the first option ?

Also, why are there three partitions sda4, 5 & 6? Should there not be one ?

When installing again, Ubuntu 12.4 LTS how can I just give it 200GB main Partition and Swap Partition of 4GB ? The first time I tried I couldn't figure out what to do in **advance partitioning**. So I let Ubuntu CD do it for me.

Any help appreciated.

---

#### How do i merge the unallocated partition with my Windows partition ?

Ok now i get this:
[image: partitioned]

But how can i add the **unallocated partition** to my windows back (sda2 i guess). When i click on sda2 resize i can't move it on the unallocated partition. I want now to merge it to my windows partition. So what should i do now ?  Should i do this from Windows, but how ?

[image: sda2 move/resize]

Comment: See also [our guide here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/how-do-i-repartition-with-gparted) - make sure you have no partitions mounted, i.e. use gparted from booting a live CD with "Try Ubuntu". Swap on a 12GB RAM system is likely only needed for hibernating. You can install without swap if you dont want to allocate that much space.

Comment: @Takkat thanks i installed already with swap as you see in picture. Live CD choose 12 GiB. Should i Shrink it ? I want the hibernation but is 12 GiB not too mch just for hibernation ? Ok i will try again cause i did not unmmount all the partitions (sda4,sda5), and also i did not Swapoff sda6. Maybe that was the problem

Comment: Ok after i unmounted everything and swapedoff sda6 i can Move/Resize dev/sda4 and then Grow sda2. That is what i wanted. Thanks

Comment: Just an additional remark: hibernating a dual boot system may cause data loss, especially when the hibernated OS had a partition mounted which was then accessed from another OS. Always wake up the hibernated OS before booting another OS to be on the safe side (note that Windows 7 fast boot option is hibernating too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot using your ubuntu CD and follow this guide:

http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/

i won't try to resize your swap. Your swap is mostly equivalent to your size of ram memory.

Evrything in sda4 is your ubuntu. sda5 is your OS and sda4 your swap.

sda2 is your windows partion, sda1 your windows system partion.

sda3 is windows recovery.

Comment: Thanks for the link. My RAM memory is 12GB. Ok then if it is so i will not touch the Swap. So sda1,sda2 and sda3 are my Windows partitions. So what should i change with GParted, sda4 or sda5 ? (I guess i should not touch sda6)

Comment: sda5 needs to shrink and sda2 need to grow. i think 200 gib for sda5 should be enough.

Comment: So i just need to unmount sda5 and resize it. I just need to move sda2 to the right, till sda5 is only 200GB as i want it to be. Is that everything ? Sorry for asking again but you said sda4 is Ubuntu, does that not need to be touched ? Will it shrink automatically ? Thanks

Comment: Correct. sda4 contains sda5 and sda6 and will shrink automatically when your shrink sda5. sda4 is a kind of holder i think.

Comment: Ok i will try that out. So i will put the CD and boot and shrink sda5. I will then report back

Comment: Hi there i did it, but now i have unallocated partition of 1.30 TiB, how can i add that to Windows 7 ? I tried to resize sda2 but i can't move it over the unallocated partition.

Comment: Boot to windows 7 (for safety). Go to diskmanagement and select grow on your windows partion and click OK.

Comment: I can't do it from disk managment, there is no option to expand the volume, actually it is grayed out. There is the free memory but i cant expand C: and use the free space partition.  But i can do it with GParted. I just need first to swapoff sda6 and then move/resize dev/sda4 to the right and shrink it from 1.52TiB to 228 GiB and then Grow dev/sda2 from 281 GiB to 1.57 TiB.