# Resize Boot Device Volume

Tags: boot, disk-usage, volume-control, resize

I'm Wondring how can I resize Boot Volume because it got 15GO of space and he use only 71.7MB only almost 0% of space. So I want to reduce This space and add it to principle Device "/"[image]

Comment: You can use [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/). [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/how-do-i-repartition-with-gparted) question + answer might be useful. You might want to double check to see if it's a good idea to tamper with /boot though.

Comment: I have already tried with Gparted but I can't find the boot partition to resize it.

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of your GParted?