# How to create partition from running onepartition?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

Hello i am new in ubuntu.
While setuping ubuntu i pressed replace windows 8 and it did.
But the problem is it also deleted other partition.
Now is there any way to slice my one partition into 2 pieces? I have 320GB HDD so i want to use 50GB for ubuntu and others for file storage.
And is there anyway to recover the datas that got deleted during installation?

I will be glad if somebody help me out

Comment: If you need to recover data you believe may be lost, it's imperative that you immediately shut down the newly installed system and not use it. You can run from a live CD *if swap is disabled*. See [the guidelines here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery). Once you've booted into an Ubuntu live CD system, please run `sudo fdisk -l` in a Terminal window (Ctrl+Alt+T) and **edit your question** to provide the full output (format it with the `<$>` tool so it appears correctly). That should show what partitions there are, and facilitate knowing if data recovery is needed.

Comment: @Fandango, we like to keep it to one question per post here at Ask Ubuntu. I think you're asking two questions: how to partition, and how to recover the deleted data. As for the deleted data, check Eliah's comments. As for the partitioning, visit this question: [How do I repartition with GParted?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/how-do-i-repartition-with-gparted)

Answer (score -1):

You can resize easily the partition with the ubuntu live cd.

You just select `Try without installing` then you run the tool `gparted` and resize your partition to which size you want. 
Then you can make another partition with the free space.

To recover data lost during installation I don't know any tool.

Comment: If data have to be recovered, it is critically important that **the partition not be resized first**. Resizing the partition with GParted before data recovery is performed might make it impossible to recover anything.