# How to extend ext4 with gparted?

Tags: grub2, partitioning, live-usb, gparted, ext4

I am having short in disk space in my ubuntu `/dev/sda6` and i have 11.08 GB of free space unallocated in the sense.I have followed different article about the repartition but they are not working here when i try to move/resize sda6 the there will not be any free space to extend but it reduce if we try.
Notice:-I know it's mounted for posting the queries i have to take screenshot so the mount option is there, i have used gparted by liveusb...

[image]

I think so `/dev/sda4` blocked other access.Please help me here about resizing the sda6.
I have also followed method of given link below:

[Why I'm seeing a lock besides the partition I'm trying to modify with gparted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/how-do-i-repartition-with-gparted)

but still not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You have to move the 11 GB unallocated space which was on the top to below or above the `/dev/sda6` ext4 partition.For this follow the below steps,
- First you have to boot from gparted live disk or Ubuntu live disk.And make sure that all the partitions are unmounted.
- Rightclick on the `/dev/sda2` partition and select Resize/Move option.Move the dragger to extreme left and then click on Apply,so that the unallocated space comes just below to the `/dev/sda2` partition.
- Do the above step again on `/dev/sda3` partition to get the unallocated space just below to the `/dev/sda3` partition.Now your unallocated space will be just below to the `/dev/sda3` partition.
- Now right-click on the `/dev/sda4` extended partition and select Resize/Move option.Click and expand the left arrow to get the unallocated space into the extended  partition.
- Now your 11 GB comes inside extended partition(just below to the `/dev/sda9` partition.
- Right-click on the `/dev/sda9` partition and select Resize/Move.Click and move the dragger to the extreme right,so that the unallocated space comes just above to the `/dev/sda9` partition.
- Do the same above step on `/dev/sda8` and `/dev/sda7`.After that,11 GB unallocated space will comes under `/dev/sda6` root partition.
- Now you can be able to resize your Ubuntu `/dev/sda6` partition.

And make sure that you had backed up all the important datas before proceeding with gparted.

Also see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/389067/202806) answer for any clarifications.

Comment: Good Article i followed as you said in the post but when i try to move/resize it occupies the place of /sda2 and occupies memories so further i tried to do with /sda3 the remaining space of c also goes away.I don't think so it will work before these i just had issue with grub rescue

Comment: try to move the dragger not expanding it.Please post the screenshot link for better understanding.

Comment: ok gotcha i was moving just let me live boot the gparted and i will let you know

Comment: let me know the step by step activities that was going to done.If you done anything wrongly,then you will face serious problems.

Comment: Note that this is a LOT of data moving, so will take a very long time.

Comment: @psusi yes,you are right.

Comment: @AvinashRaj really appreciate bro i have just increased my ext4 space..

Comment: but i have face weird problem with my windows it's not booting

Comment: did you resized your Ubuntu partition?Does the windows option shown on the grub?

Comment: no i didn't resize i just move as you said it doesn't show error on grub but after loading grub it say some weird error with disk installation

Comment: did you do all the steps i mentioned above?You got in struck on which step?

Answer (score 0):

You can't expand sda6 into that unallocated space because it isn't contiguous with it. The only room for expansion sda6 has is into the 300Mbs of unallocated space after it.

You can format the 11Gb unallocated area as ext4 and use it for storing data. That might free up some room in your Ubuntu partition.

Comment: see my answer,it's possible.

Comment: The solution is so complicated. That's because the disk partitions are in a bit of a mess too.