# Upgrade ubuntu space with windows 7

Tags: windows-7, disk-usage

I installed Ubuntu beside windows 7 and after 6 months from use it I love it and  I need to delete windows 7 space and move it to Ubuntu .

For example :
Partition c had tow systems :

1- Widows 7 30 GB

2- Ubuntu 20 GB

So I need to upgrade Ubuntu space to be 50 GB and delete widows 7

Is it possible and how to do that ?

Screen Shot :
[image]

Comment: Yes its possible.For how part, please provide your Gparted partition editor screenshot.

Comment: Which is your windows partition?

Comment: sda1 content windows 7

Comment: It needs large amount of data movements.See [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/421282/202806) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/389067/202806).

Answer (score 1):

If parttiton C is a logical drive and Ubuntu and Windows are on different filesystems/partitions then just Format Windows and resize Ubuntu from a different OS than Ubuntu (you can use a live linux burnt to usb for example)

Update:
I assume dev/sda5 is Windows and /dev/sda12 is Ubuntu.If something else then the steps to od are the same anyway.

So format /dev/sd5 partition with Windows on it. Then boot into another OS (like live Lubuntu0 and resize the partition with Ubuntu to what you want.

Comment: widows and Ubuntu on same partition

Comment: provide a screenshot.It will make things quicker to fix.

Comment: Thanks , give me 4 hur and I will :) , I am now outside .

Comment: user251046 I added it

Comment: Consider using better filesystem than ntfs.You only need ntfs to install Windows.There are programs to use ext4 filesystem in Windows.Generally EXT4 is best for most things but there are benchmarks etc available about different filesystems for different files.Also if you want to hibernate then you need large enough swap to save all data to the swap.Also why do you have so many partitions for data? It would make sense if each filesyste was the best for the type of files you have there but all are ntfs