# Creating Partitions in root?

Tags: 12.04

I was trying to install Ubuntu along with windows but accidentally I got my entire hard disk wiped out and ubuntu remained.
Now, Ubuntu is installed as considering my entire 500 gb as one drive (that too root ) with some space allocated to swap and all...
Now , is there any option so that I could make some drives out of the situation...

Any help will be great..
thanks
Piyush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course, you can use `gparted`. But the problem is that you can not edit a partition when it is mounted so you have to make a usb startup disk first (using e.g. startup disk creator which is also called `usb-creator-gtk`). If your computer has access to a DVD drive you can burn the ubuntu disk image onto a DVD as well.

When you started the computer with the live disk, open a terminal and enter

```
sudo gparted
```

When prompted for password, just press enter and then you can edit the partition table.

One general hint (which may not be applicable to your situation) is that it takes much less time if the new partition you create, lies at the *end* of the original partition and not the beginning (because otherwise gparted has to move all the original partition bit-by-bit). So, just resize the original partition and do not *move* it, otherwise the job can take a few hours.

If you want, you may be able to recover your windows partition using [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) (before repartitioning of course).

Answer (score 0):

Yes! :D but you'd have to do it from your live USB or CD. you can't resize an active partition! (an active partition is one that is being used)

Just boot from your USB/CD then open gparted and resize it :) you can follow [these](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-resize-partition) steps or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/how-do-i-repartition-with-gparted) question. Tell me if there's something you don't understand :)