# Installing ubuntu and drives partitioning

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, backup

I am shortly switching to ubuntu forever. I want to erase windows 7 and run my laptop on ubuntu. I have acer aspire 4736z laptop with intel t4400 processor, 3 gb ram, 320 gb disk.

Is 64 bit system fine?

Also i have 3 drives currently on my laptop. i wish to make them 4 drives with 80 gb 4 drives or 5 drives of 40 gb two and 80 gb 3 drives.

How can i change drives structure while installing ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Also the data i backup on an ext hard disk, will ubuntu read that disk whose data backup was done in windows?

I hope the community will help me as i have plenty of time due to fracture ;)

I need to learn about gnu, grub, wine, terminal etc.

Regards,

Harsh

Comment: This question would be helpfull.http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: Please do not ask the same question repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

This is link for installing Ubuntu [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)

During installation  choose the ’Something else’ option to create partition.

All if you want install Ubuntu & after that you want to create partition  than use Gparted or also you can first boot using USB or Live CD than create partition using Gparted.
[Gparted](https://askubuntu.com/a/256933/329692)

I hope this is help you.