# Install Windows 8 after Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: partitioning

So, I have ubuntu 14.04 LTS in a 1tb hard drive and I want to create a small partition (150GB) for Windows 8.1. I have already got the bootable drive for it, but I need to make another partition as the one I have ubuntu on is not NTFS, and windows installer asks for it.

So what steps should I follow to create a 150Gb partition then installing W8? I just need a simple answer.

Comment: Boot a Live System, install gparted and resize the partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GParted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted).

take a look at this : [How do I repartition with GParted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/how-do-i-repartition-with-gparted)

Comment: It doesn't let me resize it http://i.imgur.com/gyC3tEj.png  and I can't unmount it http://i.imgur.com/U22wZWE.png

Comment: To be able to resize/move partitions, the partitions must not be in use.
Boot from a liveCD or liveUSB, make sure no partition is mounted then launch Gparted and create the necessary partition.