# Increase the partition of Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot via Gparted

Tags: 16.04, gparted, disk-management

I wish to increase the disk space of my Ubuntu OS (ext4) drive from 70 GB by around 200 GB. Now , I followed the steps on [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/how-do-i-repartition-with-gparted) and successfully decreased the partition for my D drive from 292 GB to 54 GB. So it created an unallocated space for 241 GB as shown in the screen-shot.

Now, I wish to increase the disk space of my Ubuntu drive(ext4) from 69GB till as much as I can consume from the unallocated space.

When I right click on ext4 -> Go TO Resize -> It shows me below screen. It does not shows an option to increase the disk space. I can only SHRINK it. However, I wish to grow this space.
Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong ? 
TIA :)

[image: My Gparted GUI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the image, you need to move your `/dev/sda5` to the end of the drive putting the unallocated space between `/dev/sda7` and `/dev/sda5`.  Then you should be able to resize `/dev/sda7` to the remaining unallocated space.

To move the partition, make sure that it is not mounted.  Right click the partition `/dev/sda5` and choose Unmount.  It didn't look like it was mounted in your image.  Then right click it again and choose `Resize/Move`.  Then just drag that partition all the way to the right.

Comment: Thanks Terrance, But how do I move these partitions up-down ?
A simle drag does not works

Comment: @user2074836 Edited for moving the partition.

Comment: Hi Terence, 
Thank you,  I just did not get the last part.Well How can I drag the PARTITION TO RIGHT ? I just see a modal box for resize/move. There's no special options I can see to move the partition. :(

Comment: Ohh anks, I got it working :)

Comment: @user2074836 Glad you got it figured out and working now. :)