# Swap some space from one partition to other

Tags: mount, gparted

i am running out of space on the partition mounted as /. So i want to cut the partition sda4 into a smaller one and enlarge the sda2 partition.

But i can not unmount or resize sda4, because it is mounted in /home... so how can i fix that? See screenshot please.

[gparted_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiqyP.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I'm seeing a lock besides the partition I'm trying to modify with gparted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/why-im-seeing-a-lock-besides-the-partition-im-trying-to-modify-with-gparted)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: I just noticed... why is /dev/sda2 an ext2 partition?

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sda4 by the amount you wish to add to /dev/sda2
- **move** /dev/sda4 partition all the way right
- **move** /dev/sda3 partition all the way right
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sda2 all the way right
- click the Apply icon

**Update #1:**

I just noticed that /dev/sda2 is a ext2 partition. Very unusual. To do this properly will require a data backup, and a Ubuntu reinstall. **Don't multi-partition a 250G HDD when installing Ubuntu.**

- backup your data
- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- swapoff on /dev/sda3
- delete /dev/sda2/3/4 partitions
- install Ubuntu **without** manual partitioning
- restore your data

Comment: Did exactly that. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot resize partitions while they are in use, i.e., mounted. The easiest way to repartition is to run an Ubuntu session from the live USB or DVD and do the partitioning from there. In a live session, none of your internal hard drives are mounted by default, and gparted is directly available from a live session.

Still, repartitioning is not trivial. If partitions need to be moved, it can become a lengthy process and things may go wrong. It would be much easier and faster to 1) ensure that your backup is up to date and 2) reinstall the operating system, ensuring that this time your foresee some more space for the root partition. Reinstalling Ubuntu takes between 15 minutes and an hour depending on how recent your system is. Then, there is the time you need to put your data back. Moving a large partition, in contrast, can take several hours. If that does not finish successfully, you are facing a reinstall anyway.